# What is the difference between the time domain and the Heisenberg picture?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, quantum-optics

Suppose we have a quantum field theory with mode operators $a(\omega)$ which diagonalise the Hamiltonian, where $\omega$ is the frequency (energy). An example is given by the mode operators of the quantised electromagnetic field in a cavity, in which case $a^\dagger(\omega)|0\rangle$ is interpreted as the state of a single photon with energy $\omega$, where $|0\rangle$ is the vacuum.

There appears to be two distinct ways to give mode operators time-dependence.

1. We can define $$\tag{1} a_\mathrm{H}(\omega,t) = e^{iHt} a(\omega) e^{-iHt}  $$ which is the Heisenberg picture operator.
2. We can define
   $$ \tag{2} a(t) = \int d \omega e^{-i\omega t} a(\omega)$$ which is the time domain mode operator.

### My question

The Heisenberg picture operator $(1)$ makes sense to me: we have simply transferred the dynamics of the Schrodinger equation from the state vectors to the operators. Therefore $a_\mathrm{H}(\omega,t)$ encodes how the system evolves in time. However it is not clear to me what the interpretation of the time domain operator in $(2)$ is given by. We know that the diagonalised Hamiltonian is given by

$$ H = \int d\omega \omega a^\dagger(\omega)a(\omega) $$

in which case we have $a_\mathrm{H}(\omega,t) = e^{iHt} a(\omega) e^{-iHt} = e^{-i \omega t} a(\omega)$ so we can write the time domain operator as

$$ a(t) = \int d\omega a_\mathrm{H}(\omega,t)$$

which appears to be a wavepacket of Heisenberg picture operators. Is this the mode operator describing the creation/annihilation of a photon at time $t$?

In a nutshell: what is the difference between the Heisenberg picture and time domain, and what are their interpretations?

Answer (score 0):

It's just the difference between the interaction picture and the Heisenberg picture.

You are confusing two things: the diagonalisation of the Hamiltonian (operator on a Hilbert/Fock space) and finding the modes of a quadratic Hamiltonian. Since you are considering bosons, I'll restrict to this case.

You are considering boson modes with annihilation operators satisfying the canonical commutation relations:
$$
[a_i,a_j^\dagger] = \delta_{ij}
$$
with quadratic Hamiltonian of the form:
$$
H = \sum h_{ij}a_i^\dagger a_j
$$
with $h$ hermitian. Mode decomposition is about diagonalising $h$, which is different from diagonalising the original Hamiltonian $H$.

Mode decomposition is about finding a new set of bosonic annihilation operators $b_i$, related to $a_i$ by a unitary transformation:
$$
[b_i,b_j^\dagger] = \delta_{ij} \\
b_i = u_{ij}a_i \\
H = \sum \epsilon_kb_k^\dagger b_k
$$
with $\epsilon$ the (real) eigenvalues of $h$. Once again, $u$ is a unitary matrix, but does not act on the Hilbert space. Actually there exists a corresponding unitary operator $U$ of the Hilbert space:
$$
b_i = u_{ij}a_i = Ua_iU^\dagger
$$
but $u$ and $U$ are two distinct objects, just like $H$ and $h$.

From the diagonalisation of $h$, you can directly calculate using the quantum harmonic oscillator:
$$
e^{-itH}b_ke^{itH} = e^{-i\epsilon_k t}b_k
$$
This is the motivation behind the time domain: to coincide in a non interacting theory, i.e. when $H$ is quadratic. Now take and interacting theory like for example:
$$
H = H_0+V \\
H_0 = \sum h_{ij}a_i^\dagger a_j \\
V = \sum v_{ijkl}a^\dagger_ia^\dagger_ja_ka_l
$$
You can diagonalise $h$, which gives the same modes $b$, but now:
$$
e^{-itH}b_ke^{itH} \neq e^{-i\epsilon_k t}b_k
$$
You can still define:
$$
e^{-itH_0}b_ke^{itH_0} = e^{-i\epsilon_k t}b_k
$$
which are the operators in the interacting picture, but are different from the Heisenberg operators. Usually, you compute the latter by perturbation theory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I apologise but I do not follow your answer. Could you please provide some detail on these two points: 1. I do not see where I have mixed up diagonalisation of the single-particle Hamiltonian and the many-body Hamiltonian. I am only talking about the Fock space fields $a(\omega)$. 2. Are you claiming that $ \int d \omega e^{i \omega t} a(\omega) = e^{i H_0 t} a(\omega) e^{-iH_0 t}$?  I cannot see this. I also am not considering any interactions either, in which case the interaction picture operators are equal to Heisenberg picture operators, so Eqs. (1) $\neq$ (2)?